# How can cmake_minimum_required required version impact generated files?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour where changing `cmake_minimum_required` affects files generated by `CMake` targetting Visual Studio 2019. According to [the doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html) of `cmake_minimum_required`:

> If the running version of CMake is lower than the  required version it will stop processing the project and report an error

So it's just supposed to interrupt project generation.

But, if I create:

**main.cpp**:

```
int main()
{
#ifndef _DEBUG
#error "DEBUG flag not set"
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

and **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(hello_world)

set( CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release;MyDebug" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYDEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MYDEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}" )
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MYDEBUG "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG}" )
set( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MYDEBUG "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG}" )
set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS "Debug;MyDebug" )

add_executable(app main.cpp)
```

If I generate this project with CMake 3.24.1 for Visual Studio 2019, then it builds correctly using `MyDebug` config as `_DEBUG` compilation flag is correctly set.

However, if I change `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)` to `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24.1)`, then it fails to build, reporting `DEBUG flag not set`, meaning `_DEBUG` compilation flag is not set anymore.

When I check `vcproj` file, I see that for `MyDebug`, `<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebugDLL</RuntimeLibrary>` is changed to `<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDLL</RuntimeLibrary>`.

Is this a `CMake` bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it's just supposed to interrupt project generation.

That's not the case at all!

`cmake_minimum_required` puts your project into a *backwards compatibility* mode consistent with the version specified. The ["Policy Settings"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html#policy-settings) section of that doc talks about this. There are a set of now over one hundred CMake policies that enable breaking improvements to the system. You can see the full list here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-policies.7.html

The relevant policy here is [CMP0091](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0091.html) which was introduced in CMake 3.15.

> CMake 3.15 and above prefer to leave the MSVC runtime library selection flags out of the default `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` values and instead offer a first-class abstraction. The `CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` variable and `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` target property may be set to select the MSVC runtime library. If they are not set then CMake uses the default value `MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>DLL` which is equivalent to the original flags.

So to upgrade your project to a version of CMake newer than 3.15, you'll just need to override the default [`CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html) close to the top of your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug,MyDebug>:Debug>DLL"
    CACHE STRING "Rule for selecting MSVC runtime")
```

This uses the [`$<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:CONFIG) generator expression to enable the debug runtime for your custom `MyDebug` config.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `cmake` can change behaviour with its evolution.

> As CMake evolves it is sometimes necessary to change existing behavior in order to fix bugs or improve implementations of existing features. [`*`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_policy.html)

If it just changes some behaviour in a new version, it introduces a policy, that can explicitly switch cmake to use an old behaviour. The OLD behavior of a policy becomes deprecated by definition and may be removed in a future version of CMake.

See what is changed in the list [cmake-policies(7)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-policies.7.html#manual:cmake-policies(7)).
Also you can set `cmake_minimum_required` incrementing the major version number by one at a time, run cmake and see what policies were introduced in cmake dump. One of them is changing the behaviour of `RuntimeLibrary` and `_DEBUG`.

Comment: Note that I'm using CMake 3.24.1 in both cases, I did not change the CMake version. Do you mean that `cmake_minimum_required` does not only check if minimal version is used but it also changes it's actual behaviour?

Comment: You just using the application version 3.24.1, but set the behaviors of the versions 2.8.12 and 3.24.1 explicitly. [cmake_minimum_required - Policy Settings](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_minimum_required.html#policy-settings): *The `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION)` command implicitly invokes the `cmake_policy(VERSION)` command to specify that the current project code is written for the given range of CMake versions.*

Comment: Ok, I did not read the doc until the end, I should have done that.